# How to display output of a python program in a text box located in a .aspx Web Form?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net

I have a simple python program named hello.py

```
import sys
def Simple():
    print "Hello from Python"
```

How do I display the output of this program in a text box located in a Web Form of type .aspx.cs

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox1.Text = // Output of hello.py to be asigned to TextBox1.Text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow these steps to achieve this.

Host that python file in CGI, lets say link is `http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py` and invoke that using `WebClient` and get output. Following are code for invoking URL using `WebClient`.

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string reply = client.DownloadString("http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py"); // address = CGI hosted URL
    TextBox1.Text =  reply;
}
```

**ELSE**

Assumption: You have python installed in windows system.

1. Save python script to a file , say abc.py.
2. You can directly execute python script, using this `"c:\python26\python.exe" "abc.py"`. We will use this in next step.
3. Using process execution, we can execute the above command from C# and get output. Example-

> ```
> var proc = new Process {
>     StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
>         FileName = "c:\python26\python.exe",
>         Arguments = "abc.py",
>         UseShellExecute = false,
>         RedirectStandardOutput = true,
>         CreateNoWindow = true
>     }
> };
>
> proc.Start();
> while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
>     string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
>     // do something with line
>     TextBox1.Text  = line;
> }
> ```

**OR**  - use this link `http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html` - this shows , how to make python code REST based thing, and you can invoke directly that `REST API` in asp.net code.